# How to send two values with a rails collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to send two values with my collection select.  Currently, i'm saving the `ID` but I want to have access to the `name` in my controller as well.

`= f.collection_select :foo_id, @foos, :id, :name`

That's my code, pretty simple.  Just having trouble getting access to that name.
The collection also comes from a external API, so I don't want to have to touch the API again to get the name.

Comment: May be keep the option value as `"<name>#<id>"` and inside the controller split it on `#` and use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As, I said in the comment. You can customize the `<option>` tag values like :

```
 = f.collection_select :foo_id, @foos, ->(ob) { "#{ob.name}|#{ob.id}" }, :name
```

Now, inside the controller just *split* it the value on `|`, and use it.

This is just an idea out of millions.